# permission denied by powercfg on win7 while an administrator

Tags: windows-7, powercfg

I am trying to fix a friends computer which is constantly going to sleep on them and sometimes not waking up.

Trying to launch power configuration from the control panel does nothing, and launching powercfg.cpl from the command line results in no output or action.

I have tried powercfg /RestoreDefaultPolicies and I get an access denied error message telling me to try again as an administrator.
I am logged in as the only account on the PC, it is administrator, UAC is off, CMD.COM is "Ran as Administrator" and the PC is not part of a domain.

I also get the access denied error while running most of the powercfg, including powercfg -l.

What can I do to get powercfg to give me permissions again?

Comment: Create a new user account with admin privileges, log into it, see if you get the same behavior.

Comment: It looks as if it is something wrong with powercfg itself if it doesn't start normally from Control Panel. Maybe you try to do system restore and roll-back to previous good known configuration?

Answer (score 2):

The power configuration data is [stored in the Registry](https://superuser.com/a/1026366/380318), but all power management is done through the Power service, not with direct Registry access. To determine whether a given user has the authority to perform a power-related operation, the Power service consults a security descriptor that's also stored in the Registry, specifically in this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\SecurityDescriptors
```

The ACLs are in [SDDL format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379570(v=vs.85).aspx). For me on a working Windows 10 installation, that key has two values. `0E796BDB-100D-47D6-A2D5-F7D2DAA51F51` contains this string:

```
O:BAG:SYD:P(A;CI;KR;;;BU)(A;CI;KA;;;BA)(A;CI;KA;;;SY)(A;CI;KA;;;CO)(A;CI;KR;;;AC)
```

And `Default` contains this string:

```
O:BAG:SYD:P(A;CI;KRKW;;;BU)(A;CI;KA;;;BA)(A;CI;KA;;;SY)(A;CI;KA;;;CO)(A;CI;KR;;;AC)
```

It would be wise to store the old values somewhere in case you need to undo the change. If necessary, use the Permissions entry on the context menu of the `SecurityDescriptors` key to take ownership and assign write permissions on the key to Administrators. Restart the computer and the new power security will be in effect.

Answer (score 0):

Like Moab had suggested, create a new user in the Admin group and then try it. If you still have problems, you got corrupted system files.

After scanning for malware, try running `sfc /scannow`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve *restoring* permission issues, but is a possible *workaround*.

I would try running your commands through a SYSTEM privileged command prompt. Use the PsExec tool from Microsoft's Website, [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).

Open a normal Administrator Command Prompt (Win+X then Command Prompt (Admin)).

In it run, `psexec –i –s CMD` after changing directory (`cd`) to the executable's location. If prompted with password, enter. If asked for the SYSTEM password, it should be nothing so just press enter.

Then run the commands you were trying before as the Local System.

If you really want to restore your system, I would run, like aforementioned:

```
sfc /scannow
```

as well as these if it doesn't solve the issue

```
chkdsk c: /f /offlinescanandfix
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

Comment: How do you get from Win+X  to Command Prompt (Admin) on Windows 7?

Comment: @Scott, Unless your Windows is modified somehow. The keyboard shortcut: the Windows key (the one that looks like a flag or a window) and the letter X pressed together opens a side pane from the Start menu. In the menu, two should be listed that say "Command Prompt" one says (Admin) in parentheses. Choose that. If UAC is on it will prompt for admin password, if not on it won't prompt and will put right to the Command Prompt with Admin privileges. Otherwise, you can search "cmd" in the search box after pressing start. Right click "Command Prompt" and choose "Run as Administrator." It should open

Comment: (1) I know what the Windows key is, and what Win+X means.  (2) You seem to be talking about the Power User Menu, a.k.a. the Quick Access Menu, which is standard on Windows 8 and 10, and which *can be added on Windows 7*.  On ***un*** modified Windows 7 systems, Win+X brings up the Windows Mobility Center, which does not provide access to a Command Prompt, as far as I can see.  (3) I know how to start an elevated Command Prompt from the Start Menu, thank you.