# Programmatically read "Turn off hard disk after" value in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive, windows-registry, power-management

I'm looking for a way to programmatically read the current setting of the "Turn off hard disk after" value, located in the advanced power options in Windows 7 and later.

I'm aware of the

`powercfg -change disk-timeout-ac xx`

and

`powercfg -change disk-timeout-dc xx`

commands to set this value. However, there does not seem to be an equivalent command to read the currently set value.
Also, I couldn't find a registry setting for this.

Comment: You can always install one of these "monitor registry" tools, make your change, and see which key(s) have been updated...

Comment: [This seems to be pretty complicated](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?s=82051b9bcdf11eaeb296bd9c74b15083&t=2367973) There is one key for each power profile, and it's a GUID specific to your machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're asking on Super User instead of Stack Overflow, I'll focus on the scriptable (Registry) way of doing this.

The power settings are all accessible in the Registry under this key:

```
HKLM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power
```

The `User\PowerSchemes` subkey has an entry called `ActivePowerScheme` which - as you might guess - contains the ID of the current power plan. All IDs relating to power management are GUIDs, but my quick surveys show that the default ones are the same on all machines. The subkeys of `PowerSchemes` are, well, power schemes. `381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e`, for instance, is *Balanced (recommended)*.

[image: power options]

The subkeys of the power scheme keys are categories as they appear in the advanced power options. These are defined in the `PowerSettings` subkey of `Power`. For instance, `0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442` is *Hard disk* as seen in the above image. The subkeys of *those* are the individual settings. `6738e2c4-e8a5-4a42-b16a-e040e769756e` is *Turn off hard disk after*. Those keys have a `DefaultPowerSchemeValues` subkey, which has a subkey for every standard power plan. Those keys have an `AcSettingIndex` and a `DcSettingIndex` entry which are exactly what you think. The units used vary from setting to setting; this one uses seconds. So, you can see that the default hard drive power-off timeout for the Balanced power plan is 1200 seconds (20 minutes) when plugged in and 600 seconds (10 minutes) on battery.

[image: registry defaults]

Now back to the `User\PowerSchemes` key. Since the user might not have ever changed the settings, there's no guarantee that the key will have both AC and DC setting entries, the setting subkey, or even the category subkey. If the value you're looking for isn't there, you'll need to check the default value for the current power plan back in `PowerSettings\DefaultPowerSchemeValues`.

Note that while everybody can read these keys and values, not even Administrators can write. That's because power settings are supposed to be managed through the `Power` service, which runs as `SYSTEM`.

---

Developers of compiled (C++) applications should use the documented interface for power management. Call [`GetCurrentPowerPolicies`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372689(v=vs.85).aspx), get the [`user`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373239(v=vs.85).aspx) part of the [`POWER_POLICY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373179(v=vs.85).aspx) structure, and look at the `SpindownTimeoutAc` and `SpindownTimeoutDc` values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It pretty much completely covers the issue.